# file not found grub rescue>

Tags: grub2

let me tell you the story from the beginning i had a mutltiboot system -ubuntu,windows 7(pre-installed). as we know there is a loader(the one that give us multi os choice) that start loading from the ubuntu os  but what i do here is i just manualy format the partition (on disk manager app on windows 7 ) that has the ubuntu os (not the loader- they are distnict actually)  it was working fine until the first reboot that i met with this command for the first time

error:unknown file system 
grub rescue>

i got the answer for this and try it but it only work to load the linux one and i just already delete all the source files for ubuntu so it couldn't make it.
so i tried to get onother linux- fedora16 . amazingly the live cd  provided me with those partitons of loaders  i formated the partition of what it said 'linux swap space'. and the next reboot message was 
error:file not found
grub rescue>

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

1. Boot from a Windows Live CD (I assume you know how to modify the boot order
2. Choose Repair
3. Choose Command Prompt
4. Run `bootrec /fixmbr` then `bootrec /fixboot`
5. Profit!

Basically, you forgot to fix your MBR to boot Windows, so your computer fails to boot because it cannot find GRUB. Follow the instructions [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/) for a full guide on uninstalling Ubuntu from a multiboot setup.